# How to use inline styles with styled-components in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image, styled-components

I've a fairly simple React component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { formatUrl } from "formatUrl";

const StyledWrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 20px;
`;

const StyledImage = styled.img`
  border: solid 5px green;
`;


const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const url = formatUrl(data.foo.url);

  return (
    <StyledWrapper>
     <StyledImage></StyledImage>
    </StyledWrapper>
  );
};


export default MyComponent;
```

But I have absolutely no idea how to set `<StyledImage>` to have `background-image` with `url({url})`. The URL is getting formatted within `MyComponent` and I can't really access it outside of the component. How should I proceed in this case? Is there a generic solution to this?

I want do do something like this:

```
<StyledImage styles="background-image: url({url})"></StyledImage>
```

I know I could use "props" where describing styles for `StyledImage`, yet I'm not sure if it's a good idea to format data there, this won't scale well

**Note: I'm planning on moving my styled components to separate file in the future so `StyledWrapper` and `StyledImage` will be imported (not sure if it changes anything).**

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with the following solution general solution, which is working fine for me. I created the following **Image.js** component:

```
 import styled from "styled-components";

 const url = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";

const Image = styled.img.attrs({
  src: `${url}`,
})``;

export default Image;
```

Imported the Image Component in my **App.js** and used as `<Image />` it worked fine.

**In your case you should make following changes to make it work:**

```
const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const url = formatUrl(data.foo.url);
  // Create Image Component here as you are getting url from data props
   const StyledImage= styled.img.attrs({
    src: `${url}`,
  })`border: solid 5px green;`;

  return (
    <StyledWrapper>
      <StyledImage/>
    </StyledWrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, could you please show how to do that on my example? How am I supposed to add `<main>` to `styled.div`, I can put only CSS in there, right?

Comment: So, you are using styled components my friend. No problem. Give me a moment. Need to look something first  :) Will get back to you soon :) Hopefully

Answer (score 1):

> This should work easily.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { formatUrl } from "formatUrl";

const StyledWrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 20px;
`;

const StyledImage = styled.div`
background-image: url("${props => props.imageUrl}") center center no-repeat
  border: solid 5px green;
`;


const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const url = formatUrl(data.foo.url);

  return (
    <StyledWrapper>
     <StyledImage imageUrl={url}/>
    </StyledWrapper>
  );
};


export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).